# Regex seperate 2 numbers by komma

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a regex to allow only a case of a number then "," and another number or same case seperated by ";" like

1. 57,1000
2. 57,1000;6393,1000

So far i made this: `Pattern.compile("\\b[0-9;,]{1,5}?\\d+;([0-9]{1,5},?)+").matcher("57,1000").find();`
which work if case is `57,1000;6393,1000` but it also allow letters and don't work when case `57,1000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try Regex "(\d+,\d+(;\d+,\d+)?)"

```
@Test
void regex() {
    
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+,\\d+)(;\\d+,\\d+)?"); 
    
    Assertions.assertTrue(p.matcher("57,1000").matches());
    Assertions.assertTrue(p.matcher("57,1000;6393,1000").matches());
    
}
```

Comment: This works but it also accept letters. Anyway i can skip this by check if string contains any letters other than "," and ";". Thank you.

Comment: Other than the use of Junit testing how is this different than my answer?

Comment: then add some examples with letters and I could extend the regex. You only mentioned numbers in your question.

Comment: @WJS there is no difference but that I wrote it without knowing your answer at the same time as you

Comment: Ok.  That happens.   Well, I guess I will up vote it.  LOL!

Answer (score 2):

How about like this. Just look for two numbers separated by a comma and capture them.

```
String[] data = {"57,1000",
"57,1000;6393,1000"};

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+),(\\d+)");
for (String str : data) {
    System.out.println("For String : " + str);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1) + " " + m.group(2));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

prints

```
For String : 57,1000
57 1000

For String : 57,1000;6393,1000
57 1000
6393 1000
```

If you just want to match those, you can do the following:  It matches a single instance of the string followed by an optional one preceded by a semi-colon.

```
String regex = "(\\d+,\\d+)(;(\\d+,\\d+))?";
for (String str : data) {
    System.out.println("Testing String " + str + " : " +str.matches(regex));
}
```

prints

```
Testing String 57,1000 : true
Testing String 57,1000;6393,1000 : true
```